# Spring Batch MultiResourceItemWriter Restart Fails [File is not writable]

Tags: spring-batch

I am using **MultiResourceItemWriter** for generating files. Suppose each file will have 15 lines and chunk size is 5, then there will be 3 chunks for each file.

If an exception occurs in the second or third chunk of a file, the file gets created and it contains the data till the last committed chunk. After restart, the rest of the data is written to the file as expected.

But if an exception occurs in the first chunk of a file, the file is not getting generated. Now If I restart the failed job, I get a "**File is not writable: [filename]**" error message.

Is there a way to restart the job when the first chunk of a file fails?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, I have found this github issue about the same problem I am facing. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/845. You can reproduce it by using MultiResourceItemWriter and throwing an exception at the first chunk of a file.

Comment: ok thanks for the reference. Please add a comment on that issue on github or a reaction to upvote it.